# Homology Groups of Tangent 2-Spheres

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I have been trying to compute the Homology Groups $ H_n $ of two tangent 2-Spheres (we will call this space, X). By previous results, I am able to easily determine that $ H_0(X) $ is isomorphic to the integers and $ H_k(X) = 0 $, for $ k \geq 3 $. However, I am having trouble computing $ H_1 $ and $ H_2 $.

Up until now, I know that the $ n $-ball is homeomorphic to the n-simplex. Based on this fact, we can instead choose to analyze the two 2-simplex which intersect at one unique point (which "represents" the point at which the two 2-spheres intersect).

Comment: Are you familiar with Mayer-Vietoris sequences?

Comment: Also, the $n$-sphere is not homeomorphic to the $n$-simplex.  The $n$-ball is homeomorpic to the $n$-simplex, and its boundary, the $(n-1)$-sphere, is homeomorphic to the boundary of the $n$-simplex.

Comment: Hi @EricWofsey. I am not familiar with Mayer-Vietoris sequences. Regarding the $ n $-ball being homeomorphic to the $ n $-simplex along with the the other condition you mentioned, you are are right. I had thought that the $ n $-simplex consisted of only its boundary.

EDIT: I have corrected the original post.